# Emit и возвращение данных

Tags: qt

Есть два класса "background" и "modbus", класс "background" вызывает кнопку, которая должна переходить в другой класс и возвращать данные. Думаю проблема в emit точнее то что они работают вразнобой.

Привожу краткий пример:

```
class Background::pushbutton_clicked()  // нажимаем кнопку в классе Background
{
QByteARray ba = modbus->get_data_slot(); // переходим в класс modbus и вызываем слот
}

QByteArray Modbus::get_data_slot() // slot класса Modbus
{
ba_fon; // глобальная переменная класса modbus
return ba_fon; // по сигналу класса Modbus заходит в слот хочу добавить что сигнал написан в этом классе и скорее всего в этом проблема
}
```

Ясное дело в класс Background паровозик приходит пустым (((
Собственно хидеры подключены так: modbus -> background.

Была идея создать еще один сигнал "data complite" и передавать их обратно, но как их передать ведь будет ругаться на циклическую зависимость классов.

Comment: Вы сами прочитайте что пишете -  кнопку, которая переходит в другой класс и возвращает данные (!) Как кнопка может возвращать данные? Опишите свою задачу корректно. Тогда и в коде будет понятно что делать. А в коде у вас сейчас - прямой вызов функции слота по клику кнопки - и этот слот у вас возвращает переменную (!) - слоты в концепции QT не возвращают ничего

Comment: @Mira, и всё-таки слоты, являясь по сути обычными функциями - методами класса, могут возвращать значение. Другое дело, что emitter сигнала это значение получить не сможет.

Comment: @aleks.andr Понятно что могут, но не для этого они предназначены. Они морально не могут :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Берусь предположить, что вас интересует следующая архитектура:

> Сигнал кнопки вызывает слот объекта некоторого класса, после обработки
>   этого слота объект должен отправить некоторые данные.

Сделайте так:

```
class Receiver : public QObject
{
    ...
public slots:
    void slotReceiveAnswer(const QByteArray& data);
    ...
};

class Handler : public QObject
{
    ...
signals:
    void answerPrepared(const QByteArray& data);
    ...
public slots:
    void slotProcessing()
    {
        QByteArray answer;
        ...
        emit answerPrepared(answer);
    }
    ...
};

// использовать так:

Receiver receiver;
Handler handler;
QPushButton button;

QObject::connect(&button, SIGNAL(clicked()), &handler, SLOT(slotProcessing()));
QObject::connect(&handler, SIGNAL(answerPrepared(const QByteArray&)), &receiver, SLOT(slotReceiveAnswer(const QByteArray&));
```

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос немного сложно сформулирован, но лично я решал проблему передачи данных по слотам следующим образом:

void addFriend(QStringList *answer, const QString &login);

где слот и сигнал имеет два параметра, один для передачи данных, другой - для возвращения. ПО меньшей мере, если таскать с собой эти два указателя, то доступ и к данным и к ответам у вас будет всегда.